# The application of the open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and $V_i \subset V(i=1, \ldots, J)$ a number of closed subspaces satisfying $V=\sum_{i=1}^J V_i$, which, by a simple application of the Open Mapping Theorem, implies
$$
\sup _{\|v\|=1} \inf _{\sum_i v_i=v} \sum_{i=1}^J\left\|v_i\right\|^2<\infty
$$

I don't know how to use the open mapping theorem.

**Edit:** This claim is made in the paper *The method of alternating projections and the method of subspace corrections in Hilbert space* by Jinchao Xu and Ludmil Zikatanov. See [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2002-15-03/S0894-0347-02-00398-3/S0894-0347-02-00398-3.pdf).

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide some context as to where your question comes from? I presume you're quoting a passage from a proof that you're reading?

Comment: Your question is a legitimate question. However, it may be useful to provide more context, such as: $1)$ where the problem came from/how it arose, $2)$ Stating what the Open Mapping Theorem is. $3)$ Stating any thoughts you have on the problem. Have you used the OMT on any other problems previously?

Comment: It comes from the paper in page 577: THE METHOD OF ALTERNATING PROJECTIONS AND THE METHOD OF SUBSPACE CORRECTIONS IN HILBERT SPACE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is consider the linear map
$$ f: V_1 \times \dots \times V_J \to V$$
given by
$$ f(v_1, \dots, v_J) = v_1 + \dots + v_J.$$

Notice that:

- The codomain of $f$ is complete since $V$ is a Hilbert space.
- The domain of $f$ is also complete, since $V_1, \dots, V_J$ are *closed* subspaces of the Hilbert space $V$.
- $f$ is surjective, since $V = V_1 + \dots + V_J$.
- $f$ is clearly continuous.

So it is valid to apply the Open Mapping Theorem to $f$.

The Open Mapping Theorem tells us that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
for every $v \in V$ with $\| v \| < \delta$, there exists a $(v_1, \dots, v_J) \in V_1 \times\dots \times V_J$ with $\|(v_1, \dots, v_J) \| < 1$ such that $f(v_1, \dots, v_J) = v$.

This is equivalent to saying that there exists a $c \in \mathbb C$ such that for every $v \in V$ with $\| v \| = 1$, there exists a $(v_1, \dots, v_J) \in V_1 \times \dots \times V_J$ with $\|(v_1, \dots, v_J) \| < c$ such that $f(v_1, \dots, v_J) = v$. (For example, take $c = 2\delta^{-1}$.)

But then, for every $v \in V$ with $\| v \| = 1$,
$$ \inf_{\sum_{i = 1}^J v_i = v} \sum_{i = 1}^J \|v_i\|^2 < c^2.$$

Hence
$$ \sup_{\| v \| = 1} \left( \inf_{\sum_{i = 1}^J v_i = v} \sum_{i = 1}^J \|v_i\|^2 \right) \leq c^2 < \infty.$$

Comment: $\times$ feels more appropriate than $\oplus$? Or maybe it's different in the English-speaking world? $\oplus$ makes me think more of a direct sum (or direct product), while the $V_i$ aren't supposed to be in a direct sum. But I understand if $\oplus$ is also used in this case usually and I just didn't know. Anyway, quite a clean and neat answer! (+1).

Comment: @BrunoB I see what you mean! I had the same thought. I'm using $\oplus$ to denote an _external_ direct sum. As you pointed out the $V_i$'s are not in an internal direct sum 
hence why my original notation is confusing. I'll change it.